# Eclipse is not working in windows 8

Tags: java, eclipse

Yesterday I was using eclipse on my sytem. Today, when I am trying to run eclipse on my system, I get the following error
[image: error screen shot]

I do not know how did it happen? Please help me to solve it.

Comment: **Always always always** use `eclipse.ini` to specify the JVM you want Eclipse to run in. That way you know for sure and it eliminates the chance that a system update breaks things by updating/changing the JVM that is on your system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer from [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13):

> > I had the same error when configuring eclipse.ini to use JRE6. Turns out I caused this error by incorrectly configuring eclipse to use the
> >     64 bit JVM while running a 32 bit version of eclipse 3.7.
>
> The correct configuration required the eclipse.ini -vm argumument to
>   use "C:/Program Files (x86)/" instead of "C:/Program Files/".
>
> Make sure that the JVM version (32/64 bit) you use matches the eclipse
>   version (32/64 bit).

Comment: ok I was successfully running it yesterday but can not today?

Comment: open cmd.exe, run java -version, what does it say?

Comment: C:\Users\Shiza>java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: That appears to be 32 bit java, and (i'm guessing based on your screen shot) 64 bit eclipse. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you mentioned it was working earlier it puzzles me why its crashing now. Anyway just reinstall your JDK to match the eclipse's type i.e. 32bit or 64bit and go to your environment variables and put your java bin directory as the first entry in `'Path'` variable.