# Cant get Eclipse to run, exit code 13

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm studying a MOOC on Android programming and I've downloaded three zips (the ADT that includes Eclipse, a Java Developers Kit and a game framework that is used in the course).

I'm getting exit code 13 when i try to run eclipse.

I'd post an image of the error message but I don't have enough reputation. :o/

The course tutor suggested that my Eclipse INI is corrupt. It looks okay from what I can see except it doesn't seem to have any line breaks like the examples I've seen elsewhere. Of course I don't really know what I'm looking at so if there was an odd character missing I wouldn't know. The tutors are swamped with people on the course and I don't think they are looking for messages from people two weeks behind so I don't expect much help there.

Other research has suggested that I had multiple installations of Eclipse (or possibly other parts of the course materials). I have gone back and started the download steps now about five times in the last two weeks and I did keep the old downloads in renamed folders but I've now deleted them in case they were creating an issue.

The other possibility (as suggested in another thread) is that the paths in the INI file are broken. Unfortunately I don't know anything about the syntax to be able correct a broken path to another folder. After reading the other thread I tried deleting everything related to the course and unpacked everything anew and left it excatly where it unpacked.

Can anyone shed any light on this because the MOOC tutors and mentors aren't any help, I'm two weeks behind eveyone else and the I've run out of ideas?

I've seen solutions to this that suggest relinking but you may have to tell me the fundementals of links or tell me where to go to read this up.

I'm running Windows 7 Pro, 64bit, SP1.

(I asked this question on the end of anotrher thread earlier but it looks as though it was deleted, sorry to get things wrong but I 'm trying to figure out how this forum works and I didn't want to start another thread unnecessarily.)

I think I can now post images. Here's the error message.
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Comment: Have you upgraded to java 8? If so - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/

Comment: Exit code 13 is almost always running 64 bit Eclipse with 32 bit Java (or the other way round). You must run both 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure I understand you. I downloaded everything according to the instructions on the course, which were not that great. I know I picked 64bit on the software developers kit as it says 64 in the folder name. I'm not sure about the JDK (I think that's the Java Developers Kit). The release note does say OS_ARCH="amd64" which seems to mean 64 bit but I'm not really sure.

What about software that I previously had installed on my machine before I started the course such as my existing installation of Java?

I might be able to post an image now. I'll try in another comment.

Comment: You need 64-bit java. So, goto java.com and get the right version.

Comment: Thank you @iheanyi, for your comprehensive and supportive comment. Now doesn anybody else have anythoing useful to say that might actually be useful to me? For instance how do I find out which version I'm running? 

If there's anybody else out there who isn't interested in helping a newbie and just wants to state the obvious that I'd really rather not hear from you.

Comment: Ok, clearly you don't know much about computers. There are only two versions of Java you could possibly be running, 32-bit or 64-bit. That error says you only have 32-bit installed. Your Eclipse and Android SDK require 64-bit. If you had gone to java.com, you could actually check the version you are running from there. Giving you commandline instructions didn't seem helpful since the version displayed won't actually answer your question and frankly, my evaluation of your computer skills keeps dropping - especially since others have already given you the answer and yet here you still are.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that you don't have 64-bit java installed. You have 32-bit.

Here is the link to the jdk download page from java.com: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#javasejdk

Download and install 64-bit jdk, latest version should be ok. If the installer doesn't add it to your PATH, then you should do that after installation.

Problem solved.