# Pop up while starting eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Facing the error shown in screenshot while trying to open eclipse.
I updated my java version to 1.8.
Although as hit and trial i modified the file to java version of 1.8 but it didnt work , please help.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What the error says? where is the screenshot? I see "Thanks" only.

Comment: Please post the screenshot or give more information about the error.

Comment: Not able to post the screenshot ... because of less than 10 reputation

Comment: Link and I'll edit it in

Comment: Added the link, please help

Comment: Can you please post your `eclipse.ini` file. Also have a look at [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) which may helps you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add -vm option

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin   <-- full path to 64 JVM
```

at the beginning of eclipse.ini

Comment: Thanks 
It is working. But can you give me the detail of this problem . like why it is required to add the path of java manually.

Comment: By default Eclipse finds JRE thru JRE_HOME, Java update probably removed old JRE and now your JRE_HOME points to unexisting path