# unable to run eclipse - luna- php

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried many ways to resolve this myself before posting in SO, but I could't resolve. Please help

My **system** details: Windows8, 64 bit OS, x64-based processor

**Eclipse** I downloaded: eclipse-php-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip [ http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-php-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip ]

**Java** installed : jdk**1.8**.0_45

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45
```

[downloaded source : Windows x64    180.44 MB   jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html]

**Problem:**
On running the eclipse.exe, I get an error saying `'Java was started but returned error code=13'`

I even changed the eclipse.ini to add the vm argument,

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

Tried this SO post too [Eclipse: Java was started but returned error code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019786/eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-error-code-13)

Comment: When you run `java -version` in the command prompt, do you see `64-bit` in the output?

Comment: yes i see that , this is the snapshot. `C:\Users\java>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode) `thanks for looking into the issue @ChetanKinger. Please note that I could execute it successfully now by making the change as posted as answer.

Comment: The reason why I asked was I once faced an issue while using a 64-bit JDK with a 32-bit eclipse and the only way to resolve it was to modify the eclipse shortcut file and append the path to java after the path to eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting in SO itself resolved the problem, which i was struggling for 1 hr!!.
For sharing the screenshot of my error, I thought of copying the eclipse to 
a different folder directly inside my *'E'* drive, and that resolved my issue.
Looks like having a '**#**' in the location path created that issue!!!

Current eclipse location

> E:\eclipse-luna-php\eclipse
>   [working]

Former eclipse location:

> E:\spider#\eclipse-php\eclipse-php-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse
>   [error]

[or]

> E:\spider#\eclipse-luna-php\eclipse  [error]