# Installed java 64 bit but still gettin error opening eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was using java 32 bit and eclipse juno 32 bit till yesterday.Today i installed java 64 and eclipse luna 64 bit on my computer.My OS is Windows 7 64bit.

I am getting this error when i try to open eclipse.[image]

I have looked at many solitions but none of them worked.

My console when asked for java version shows.
[image]

And my

> > JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
> >
> > JDK_HOME is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05

And the Java folder in programs(X86) folder is as
[image]

The version shown in console is 1.7.0_79 , but the version in the error message is not the same.Where am i going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019786/eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-error-code-13

Comment: another possible duplicate target is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13?lq=1

Comment: and another with even more votes and answers is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Your JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME is still pointing to the 32bit version.
You must change them to the 64 bit version or edit your eclipse.ini with the following command:

```
-vm [path to 64 bit jdk]
```

Comment: The -vm parameter? Go to your eclipse directory and edit the "eclipse.ini" file. More information can be found here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Answer (score 1):

Programs in `Program Fies (x86)` are 32 bits version
Change your `JAVA_HOME`and `JDK_HOME` ( you might aswell check `PATH`) to point to your 64 bit installation (should be `c:\Program Files\Java`)