# eclipse cannot open if extracted in other than C drive

Tags: java, eclipse

SHORT STORY OF MY PROBLEMS:
I did extract eclipse in "C:\" and used it also created workspace along with eclipse folder then I need to install windows 7 and for that I moved my workspace to another drive(in D:\prog).

Now to avoid deleting my eclipse again when need to format C drive I have extracted eclipse along my workspace folder(in D:\prog). Now eclipse shows error while opening, it show different-different error like sometime exit code=13, sometime exit code=1, but when I sorted out these error by editing eclipse.ini file then it shows failed to create the JVM.

I have read the link I have been gave, but still showing exit code=13, this is my .ini file...

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
    -product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256M
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.appendVmargs
    -vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javaw.exe
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019786/eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-error-code-13

Comment: I have edited my question based on the editing I did after reading link you gave @aurelianr

Comment: You should only have one `-vm` line in the eclipse.ini. Error 13 means you are using a 64 bit Eclipse with a 32 bit JVM. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: C:\Users>java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: as you can see my jvm is 64 bit and also my eclipse (eclipse-jee-mars-2-RC3-win32-x86_64), so both are 64 bit @greg-449

Comment: You should only have **one** `-vm` line and its value should be on a separate line. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: sorry I forgot to update my .ini file now it is updated as shown above.<br>P.S.: still got exit code @nitind