# Cannot download or install eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The download doesn't start and when I download "eclipse-java-2020-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip" and run the application, it gives this message.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a 32 bit Java, you must use a 64 bit Java (and it must be at least Java 11).

Comment: @greg-449 Didn't that use to be an exit code 13?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter the command `java -version`. Then [edit] your question and post the output you get from that command. After that, and also in a Command Prompt window, enter the command `where java`. This will tell you how many different java versions are installed. Also check whether the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set and what is its value if it is.

Comment: If you can, please copy and paste the stack trace instead of including it as an image.

Comment: Thank you @Abra as I did not have the jdk and JAVA_HOME in my environment variable.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No.

Comment: @howlger Was in https://stackoverflow.com/q/27019786/53897

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen From _"a might cause b"_ you cannot conclude _"b means a"_. Look into the [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library).

Comment: @howlger Hence a question mark.  At that time exit code 13 at stackoverflow almost always meant "32/64 bit mismatch".  Glad things are better now.  Thank you for pointing me at the source code, but it would be more helpful and I would appreciate your efforts more if you pointed to the actual source line in play here.

Comment: It appears from an incomplete, unscientific, quick survey that the behavior changed with the major rewrites needed for Java 9.  https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198527/

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen For exit code 13 look [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library/eclipse.c#n48) and [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/src/org/eclipse/equinox/launcher/Main.java#n1528). Exit code 13 means in most cases 32/64 bit mismatch. But here it's the most unspecific exit code 1, which does not mean no 32/64 bit mismatch either. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe` is what looks like 32 bit.

Comment: @howlger Sounds like a good time to ponder on why the official Eclipse downloads do not include a tested and compatible JRE to run on by default.  The IBM Rational products did last time I used them.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Some (3 of 13) already have it, more will come. Oracle has prevented this from happening earlier.

Comment: @howlger I know that Oracle prohibited this earlier with their JDK license.  Now with both OpenJDK and j9 the times have changed.  Glad to hear that Eclipse is catching up to IntelliJ.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Oracle has prevented this from happening earlier as Eclipse Strategic Member, not with their JDK license.

Comment: @howlger Must have been a while back (but again Eclipse is old).  This bug from 2012 is about an Oracle employee wanting a JRE bundled with Eclipse to go in the App Store - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374791#c4 - when was this prevention?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen See page 9f: https://www.eclipse.org/org/foundation/boardminutes/2019_03_26_Minutes.pdf#page=9 (see also [Eclipse bug 506244](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506244)). Embedded Java 11 and 14 JREs/JDKs that can be installed into Eclipse (if it's not already included) are provided by the [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/) project.

Comment: @howlger Very interesting.  Thank you.  If I read the minutes correctly, Oracle as you said essentially vetoed shipping OpenJ9 as a default runtime for Eclipse in 2019.    Wonder what "properly licensed" would mean?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Oracle did not agree, which was effectively a veto. After the rules have been changed, a Yes from Oracle is no longer required. JustJ offers HotSpot VMs only. The license of OpenJ9 is a bit different and no downloads of OpenJ9 VMs are provided from eclipse.org although OpenJ9 is an Eclipse project in contrast to HotSpot (I don't know what exactly the point is here). And also [AdoptOpenJDK becomes Eclipse Adoptium](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2020/06/adoptopenjdk-to-join-the-eclipse-foundation/).