# Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I've been trying to simply install Eclipse, but something went wrong apparently... I've even tried uninstalling Java and re-installing the latest Java hoping that would do something, but still nothing.

Here's what I get when I run the eclipse.exe file (This is a temporary laptop by the way):

http://gyazo.com/ccbc408dcf1bdbcbfae0143600eb58cd

Now I barely know anything about computers and all, so I'll need a really numbed down explanation... any help is appreciated!

~Deion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Comment: Could you post output of 'java -version' within Command Prompt?

Comment: @Delon Sorry forgot to mention, I was interested in the architectue, either its x86 or x64. If you have a 64bit eclipse you also need 64bit java. But if you have a 32bit eclipse and a 64bit java, you shouldn't have any problems. You can see from the image you've provided that you have a 32bit java.

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and almost certainly a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: @greg-449 I'll go change that right away and see what happens.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh god you're a life saver, it's finally installing. Thank you so much! Can't believe I missed something so simple...

Comment: Rollback because OP's edit made question incomprehensible

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading a clean copy of Eclipse from [their website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?). If that doesn't work, make sure you have both a 64-bit version of Eclipse and a 64-bit version of the JDK (or 32-bit Eclipse and 32-bit JDK). This can be solved by the version of the JDK required and editing the `eclipse.ini` file and adding filepath to the JDK.

For example:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

where `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`is the path to the file.