# Why Java 1.6 and not Jdk 8 for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse from official site and they mentioned that it is supported by Java 8 but when I try to run it I get return code = 13 error. So should i uninstall Java 8 and install Java 1.6.

Comment: Why would you install 1.6? It should work absolutely fine with Java 8 - that's what I've got here. Does it not start at all? Do you get a logo or anything? Have you specified anything in eclipse.ini? What operating system are you using? Without any more information, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I see no indication that the OP has got as far as that - from what is written, it sounds like Eclipse itself isn't starting.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for correcting me. I mis-read the question.

Comment: add to that the version of Eclipse you're using? Some work with java8 and some earlier ones not. Also Java 1.6 is EOL IIRC

Comment: I think it may that the bits don't match. 64 bit IDE with 32 bit JDK, or vice versa. I always get the 2 mixed up when I do a fresh install of the OS. 1.8 works great for me on Eclipse Luna, and Luna has the syntax support for it as well

Comment: yes eclipse give me error 13...saying that it needs java 1.6 when I checked my command prompt using "java -version" I get Java 1.8...I have downloaded "eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64" from eclipse and "jdk-8u20-windows-x64" from Java

Comment: Well, I don't think that is says it needs Java 1.6. More likely it says that it requires ***at least*** Java 1.6.

Comment: You should be getting error window like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13). Please attach its full contents.

Comment: I am reinstalling Java again...I will also edit the ini...lets see what happens..

Comment: re installing worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run Eclipse on a Mac, and I had that problem the first time I downloaded it.  I uninstalled Eclipse, and the Java version I was running.  I then reinstalled first the Java 8 SE and JDK, THEN I ran downloaded the latest version of Eclipse.  That seemed to work for me.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not necessary to download eclipse Luna if it is already installed. (Also eclipse Kepler had a patch to support Java 8.)

Comment: What system are you using?