# Eclipse- Start up erorr

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I just upgraded form Java 1.7.51 to Java 8 and Eclipse stopped running. I made the changes and explicitly declared the VM (as you can see in the image). It started with an error that VM (2048MB) could not be allocated so I removed the XMX setting.

Is there something I missed? What have I done wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: See also the first, second, and third results for Google search "java exit code 13".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run the 64-bit version of Eclipse ("...launcher.win32.win32.x86_**64**") with a 32-bit JVM (It's in "Program Files **(x86)**"). Check to make sure you've installed the 64-bit version of Java 8.