# Cannot start aptana studio on win7 with java1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, aptana

I tried installing **Aptana Studio 3.6.1** on my Win7 machine 64 
bits.  When I try to start it I get a complaint regarding the JVM.  So I 
changed the Target shortcut to execute the following command instead:

```
"C:\Users\Slark\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe"
```

When I try to run it, I get error code 13. I'm not sure what's wrong and what I need to do to get this application to start.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) help?

Comment: Good to read. So please close this as duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) (I already voted for "that's more a question for [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)"