# Eclipse Unable to Launch After Java Update 8

Tags: java, eclipse

After installing the recent Java update, I get error code 13 along with some extra text:

[image: eclipse error message]

I did not have this issue with any other Java update but the recent Java 8 update. I have tried downloading the most recent version of Eclipse Luna, which is supposed to have support for Java 8, but no luck. Is anyone else having this issue? If not, can someone help me decipher this to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to use a 32-bit JRE on a 64-bit system. That's possible, but you have a 64-bit version of eclipse (you can't do that). Download a 64-bit version of the JRE.

Comment: So Java's updater installed the wrong JRE? That's stupid, but apparently true since getting the 64 bit JRE worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your eclipse.ini is messed up. From the message: the vm option and its value is on the same line. The value should be on the line below (this is the issue that I had earlier):

```
The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
```

A google search brought me to this:

[Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

EDIT 1: The same link also talks about misconfiguring a 64 bit JVM on a 32 bit eclipse. That could also be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Really easy fix for me: in eclipse/eclipse.ini, I changed the line:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin
```

to the new JRE directory name:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin
```

which I found in C:\Program Files\Java. So it was basically changing a 5 to a 6. The problem was that the Java update changed the directory name for the JRE, so the eclipse.ini file was pointing to the wrong directory name.

Answer (score -2):

Did you install the new java8 software with the Eclipse?
I mean you go to help/install new software/ add.
give your file localtion where the java is present in archive.
I guess it should work try it out.