# Eclipse.exe run issue - exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7

I'm trying to install the latest version of Eclipse on Windows 7. When I try to run it, I get this message. What is `exit code=13`?

[image]

JVM: [Version 8 Update 40](https://java.com/en/download/)

In command prompt, java version gives **1.8.0_40**

I've read [about error code 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13), but this did not help.

Also, I tried some of the things in command line mentioned in the answer below, but `eclipsec.exe` is blocked by the same message and doesn't allow me to type anything in.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had downloaded java from [this link](https://java.com/en/download/), which defaults to 32-bit. I run 64-bit Eclipse on 64-bit Win 7 OS. I went to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) download list of JRE options, and installed 64 bit. It works

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're giving it a java argument it doesn't like or you have a java version issue.

Try to start from the command line using eclipsec.exe and add the -debug -consoleLog parameters so that it gives you more info.

I see also that you're using the 64 bit version of eclipse, therefore you will also have problems if it's trying to use a 32bit JVM or you're using a 32bit OS.

To determine if the JVM is 32 or 64 bit open a command prompt and type: 
    java -version

Comment: Figures, that's one of the biggest Eclipse issues I've been seeing for the past few years from new users.