# Eclipse Will Not Start Error 13

Tags: java, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

Eclipse worked fine for months, all of a sudden I'm getting error code 13 when trying to start. Searches indicated this was from incompatible "bitness" of java. I've since downloaded a new copy of eclipse, uninstalled all copies of java, reinstalled just x64 & run eclipse x64, uninstalled & tried x86 with 32 bit eclipse & every other possible combination.

Right now if I run eclipse with its own copy of the JDK folder locally I either get error code 13 if I use 32 bit java with 32 bit eclipse, or "Failed to load the JNI Shared library" if I use the 64 bit copy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: off-topic: if you can try intellij idea - you won't get back to eclipse :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if this can help you.

According to this site, there are some Reasons to the error, see the link above that explain how to fix it.

Reason 1: The most common reason behind this problem is, we are trying to install different bit version-that is, 64 bit or 32 bit  version of the software. It maybe either Eclipse or Java.

Reason 2: Configuration mistake in Eclipse.ini  file

Reason 3: Special characters ( #, !, @) in Eclipse installation directory

Reason 4: You maybe using latest version of Eclipse, but you might be using  wrong version or unsupported version  of Java Virtual Machine (JVM)

http://www.ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'd already read & tried all of that.

The solution was absolutely ridiculous:
I noticed when I tried to verify java via browser all I was getting was a grey box, and java applets on other pages were failing. After hours of insanity I noticed I was having some network issues with other apps as well.

Turns out a permissions error on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces{(my interface id)} caused Java to crash globally for any user in the system running any app in the system.

This was causing random errors such as

> NoClassDefFoundError
>   Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder

This interface wasn't even in use & in fact didn't exist any more, but when I tried to open the key I got an Access Denied error. After I took ownership of this key & deleted it java works everywhere again.