# Eclipse Fails to Load (Exit Code 13) on fresh Fedora 22 w/ latest OpenJDK

Tags: linux, eclipse, fedora, java

Alright, before you chop off my head, I've spent the last two days poking around the internet trying to find a solution, and I'm at my wit's end. Additionally, I can't seem to login to askFedora, so here I am.

So, having installed Eclipse through the terminal via

```
sudo dnf install eclipse
```

trying to run it returns the following error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver,newState
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-Declipse.p2.skipMovedInstallDetection=true
-jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20150513-1800.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150513-1759/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib64/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150513-1800/eclipse_1608.so
-startup /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20150513-1800.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata d60001
-protect master
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver,newState
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-Declipse.p2.skipMovedInstallDetection=true
-jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20150513-1800.jar
```

I understand this to indicate there's a problem with the way I have eclipse.ini configured; specifically, what JVM I have it pointing to. `whereis java` returns `/usr/bin/java`, and in `/etc/eclipse.ini` I have the following two lines:

```
-vm
/usr/bin/java
```

`java -version` meanwhile returns

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b13)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

which, if I'm not mistaken, indicates that I have the latest OpenJDK Runtime Environment installed.

So, I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The problem - and the solution - are explained here:

[Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

2. Please run `whereis java` and `ls -l /usr/bin/java`.
3. If you happen to have multiple JDKs, you should also consider
   [alternatives](http://tech.lanesnotes.com/2008/03/using-alternatives-in-linux-to-use.html).
   For example, run `alternatives --display java`.

*NOTE*:

> The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.

====================  ADDENDUM  ====================

1. Make sure your JDK and Eclipse are either *BOTH* 32-bit, or *BOTH*
   64-bit.
2. Here are the details from my system:

   `alternatives --display java`

   java - status is auto.
    link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el7_0.x86_64/jre/bin/java
   ...

   `cd /opt/eclipse;file eclipse`

   eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped

   `cat cat eclipse.ini`

   -startup
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
   --launcher.library
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
   -product
   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -showsplash
   org.eclipse.platform
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256m
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   --launcher.appendVmargs
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx512m
3. At this point, I would strongly encourage you to either run `eclipse
   -clean` or (better!) delete and re-install Eclipse.  Make *no* changes to the default eclipse.ini, until you get it working.

I hope that helps!

Comment: 1) Tried some of that stuff on that page, still no luck.

2) `whereis java` returns `/usr/bin/java` and `ls -l /usr/bin/java` returns `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Jun 5 01:41 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java`. Changing the value for `-vm` to `/etc/alternatives/java` yielded no progress.

3) `alternatives --display java` indicates that the 'best' version of java on my system is located at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-36.b13.fc22.i386/jre/bin/java`. Changing `eclipse.ini` to reflect this yields no progress - though I notice it's referencing an i386 version, while I'm on x86_64

Comment: Additionally, changing the line under `-vm` from `/usr/bin/java` to `"/usr/bin/java"` returns a different error:

`A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
"/usr/bin/java"`

Comment: Please see my comments above

Comment: Thanks for the additional help. `alternatives --display java` returns `Current 'best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-36.b13.fc22.i386/jre/bin/java.` I understand this to mean I'm running 32-bit OpenJDK, but I can't seem to figure out how to download the 64-bit version.

Comment: `dnf list '*openjdk*'` indicates that `java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64` and `java.1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64` are both installed. I'm certain that the 64-bit edition of Eclipse is installed. How can I find the 64-bit version of OpenJDK and get Eclipse to point at it?

Comment: [alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives) "...creates, removes, maintains and displays information about" your multiple installed JREs/JDKs.  As "root", run `alternatives -config java` and just select a different version#: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Installation_Guide/sect-use_alternatives_to_set_default_JDK.html

Answer (score 0):

I came here to locate the same answer and eventually found this JIRA about this exact problem and removing the lines form the ini file worked:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-3450

Comment: It would be useful to copy the relevant information to your answer here, in case the linked page becomes inaccessible in the future.