# Multiple java versions installed and java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not able to start eclipse on Windows 7. It was working fine yesterday. Here is the screenshot of error when I start eclipse:

[image: Eclipse error when I start eclipse]

Java versions from **CMD**

[image: java and javac versions]

Why it gives different versions for `java` and `javac`?

My java home is set to Jdk 7 as below:

`JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60`

**Note:** I have jdk 8 installed on my machine but I have not set jdk 8 path.

This question has been asked couple of times but I am not able to resolve it on my machine so please do not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Do you have a java 8 JDK? or just JRE? Since the compiler is 7. Probably Windows have set the Java 8 in %PATH%, which is loaded before %JAVA_HOME%... `which java` in cmd

Comment: @Danielson I have java 8 JDK, and my `%PATH%` has `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: Check whether you have 7 in your `environment variables`. Or, just uninstall Java 7 from your computer. java 8 can also compile to Java 7...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the environment variables check your path whether it is starts with `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

if yes then please remove it and try again

Comment: yes, it start with `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;`

Comment: remove and then restart cmd. check javac -version now

Comment: it worked, I am curious why `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` is appended in `%path%`

Comment: this will append while installing java8 and above

Answer (score 3):

More than likely you've installed `JDK 1.70_60` prior to installing `JRE 1.8.0_51`.

This would mean that your compiler `javac` is found within the JDK distribution (Java Development Kit) and your `java` runtime is found within the more recently downloaded JRE (Java Runtime Environment). JRE does not contain the `javac` (Java compiler).

Answer (score 2):

I was recently facing the  same issue, Java 8 installer prepends to the Windows PATH variable `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` that is why you are seeing different versions for `java` and `javac`

Answer (score 1):

Your eclipse might not be pointing to the right JDK.

Open your eclipse.ini configuration file for editing. This can be found in the same folder with eclipse.exe file.

replace:

```
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
```

with:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/javaw.exe
```

Then, restart eclipse.

Comment: Could be but `java -version` says 7. So Windows is configured wrong

Comment: The `-vm` parameter overrides your windows environment variable.

Comment: or you can try to remove the entire `-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe` line. The eclipse should use the JAVA_HOME variable on its next restart.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed jdk 8. Java 8 installer prepends to the Windows PATH variable `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and this is the reason I was seeing different versions for `java` and `javac`

For those who runs on the same issues, I have found nice explanation [here](https://douglascayers.wordpress.com/2015/05/30/how-to-set-custom-java-path-after-installing-jdk-8/)