# Why am I getting an error message when trying to install the Java SDK on Windows 7?

Tags: java, sdk, installation

I installed the Eclipse IDE, but it said I needed to install an SDK in order for it to run. I downloaded it from Oracle, but had trouble getting it up and running. I have Windows 7, and it says "exit code = 13".

Comment: on which OS & if it is windows then check 32 or 64 bit

Comment: What do you mean by "trouble"? Please be specific, or we can't help!

Comment: specify the error first !!!

Comment: Its Windows 7. The error message says "return exit code 13".

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13] (exit code 13 from eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do these steps:

```
1. Download JDK. e.g JDK 7. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html
2. Install it in your Windows
3. Check current version that is success or not by go to cmd and type: java -version
4. Start your Eclipse.
```

If you still have error, Google it for the detail.
 Hope this help.