# Aptana Studio reporting syntax error when accessing array element

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, aptana, aptana3

I am running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044.
I don't understand why it is reporting the following as
a syntax error given that it was working fine in vim
and could run the code in XAMPP with no errors:

```
$key = array_keys($myArray)[0];
```

Why is Apatana reporting a syntax error here and how do I fix it?

Comment: It's called array dereferencing. it's only available in 5.4+, so I'd suspect, either your local version of PHP isn't that high, or Aptana has its own parser that doesn't know about it. (Never used Aptana).

Comment: As of today I am running the latest version of XAMPP with PHP Version 5.6.11 as well as the latest version of Aptana Studio 3. I guess Aptana has some catching up to do. Anyways, isn't array dereferencing simply accessing an array element with the square brackets notation? If not, then what is the problem? And how do I fix it in Aptana Studio 3?

Comment: No, use of the square brackets is simply array access generally, until 5.4, it had to be used on an array, it could not be used against a function / method call whether or not that call returned an array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that Aptana 3 does not support some syntax available in new versions of PHP. To fix it in Aptana, do the following:

```
$keys = array_keys($myArray);
$key = $keys[0];
```

Alternatively, switch to another IDE such as for instance the [PHP version of eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-php-mars-R-win32-x86_64.zip), and read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) to get started.

Comment: Just sayin', but personally, having to modify your code to match the syntax  of an EOL version of PHP for the sake of an IDE doesn't sound much like a fix to me. *shrug*

Comment: Yes, it's true. I'm going to try and install the PHP version of eclipse and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

On Apatana Studio 3, right click your project. Click "Properties" from the drop down menu. Go to "PHP Development" then select PHP 5.4x or higher.