# -vm option ignored in eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm going mental on this one, but it's nearly impossible to specify the VM in my eclipse.ini.

Situation:
I installed Eclipse Mars (64bit) and I installed 64bit JDK.  Everything went fine until I installed the Tomcat plugin (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-tomcat-plugin).  After that, I couldn't start Eclipse anymore with the famous Exitcode 13.

I did some googling myself and I found out that this is probably because my Java is 64bit and Eclipse isn't (or the other way around).  I can already confirm that this is not the case.

Output of java -version:
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

I used the Eclipse installer, which is 64bit.

I specified the VM in my eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
D:/development/tools/java8/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```

But the error still appears.  Anyone has another idea?  I already found out that Eclipse looks within it's own directory and then checks the eclipse.ini.  As far as I can see, it ignores everything it comes across.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: We need to see the complete eclipse.ini

Comment: Well, delete the tomcat plugin :)

Comment: -vm must appear before -vmargs