# Eclipse not opening - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse

Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13
I just installed eclipse for java programming and after downloading when I tried opening the eclipse.exe file, this appeared.
I am new to programming and am unable to understand how to get past this.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds the same like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4945413/6287240) question/answer.

Comment: Try start it in the command window and capture any error messages?

Comment: You are running a 32 bit Eclipse with a 64 bit Java (or the other way round). They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update both 32 and 64 bit jre to latest versions available and your problem resolves automatically

Comment: Maybe you can upvote answer so  that others can use the solution