# Eclipse starting error. exit code 13

Tags: eclipse

Am getting this error message when I tried to start eclipse. I have added this line to eclipse.ini file but seems like its not working.
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe

Help me to fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: This looks like you might be running into the issues descrbd at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13?rq=1

Comment: You are using a 32 bit Eclipse with a 64 bit Java. They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.