# Java started but returned with exit code 13

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, exit-code, gemfire

I am trying to install GemFire but I am running into a java error which I assume is because I have multiple versions of java installed.  I started with only JRE 6 but then I installed JDK 8 and finally JRE 8.  GemFire needs to run with JDK 8 and JRE 8 but I am not exactly sure how to specify this.  When I try to run GemFire now, I get the following error:

Java exit code 13

[image]

Comment: What versions (incl. 32/64bit) of Java and Gemfire are you using?

Comment: Your STS code is 32 bit, you must run it with a 32 bit Java - or switch to 64 bit STS and run with 64 bit Java.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be while starting the Spring Tool Suite (STS) and not GemFire. STS is built on top of eclipse so maybe this thread [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) can help you.

Comment: You should mark it as duplicate, instead of answering it here. Your answer doesn't carry any additive information!