# eclipse adt bundle installation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

[adt installation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PkBy.png)

I try to run the eclipse from adt bundle on my laptop windows 8.1  but I encountered those problems(see the image). Someone can help me fix those problems?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945178/2670892 You have a 32 bit Eclipse and a 64 bit Java. They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit. Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for quite some time, use Android Studio.

Comment: thank you sir for the answer and also for the info. I'll try to use android studio instead