# Unable to run eclipse MAT for SAP Heap dump analysis

Tags: java

I have installed Eclipse MAT for windows x64_86 for analysing SAP Head Dump. But I am unable to open the MAT tool.It is throwing the below error.Please help.
[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhIfE.png)

Comment: Which JRE your process uses? Oracle or IBM

Comment: IBM 32 BIT Runtime Env for Java V8

Comment: Here exit code is 13 . Attaching the link of similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13