# Anypoint Studio Exit Code=13

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I noticed that the jre folder inside the Program Files is empty may be because of the some software update.
so had to download the jre, unzip it and then place it inside the same path as mentioned in the AnypointStudio.ini

```
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar 
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417 
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe 
-vmargs 
-Xms512m 
-Xmx1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/AnypointStudio/workspace 
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a 64-bit vs 32-bit issue. Please verify that both JRE and AnypointStudio are belongs to same bit version.
Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) for similar issue.

Comment: The binaries were missing inside the bin and jre folders for which I had to reinstall java and set the variable props in windows.

Answer (score 0):

This post from the Mulesoft site resolve my issue with this error. If you have multiple Java executables in your Path and the executable you add for the JDK needed for Mulesoft Anypoint Studio is not the first Java executable in your path, you will get this Exit Code = 13 error. Moving the new executable to the beginning of my path fixed the issue and Anypoint now runs.

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-13717?attachmentViewMode=list