# Eclipse is not starting on macOs

Tags: eclipse

I have an issue with Eclipse,
Eclipse macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6
I keep getting JVM terminated exit code=1

[image: I keep getting JVM terminated exit code=1]

I have tried too many times but the response is same after launching it.
I have downloaded it from Stanford's SEE section and still unable to launch. The error message is here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: The error message is where? What did you download, and from where?

Comment: What version of Eclipse. What version of Java?

Comment: I did download it from Stanford website where it is included in CS106A course. My java version is 1.8.0_91 and eclipse version is 3.2 for macOS X.

Comment: They posted a version of Java to go with that version of Eclipse. Did you try that?

Comment: Eclipse 3.2 is **12** years old and may not understand Java 8 or macOS 10.13. Is it a 64 bit build, 32 bit builds don't work with recent versions of Java on macOS.

Comment: Actually if this is Eclipse 3.2 there is no 64 bit build for macOS. Since Java 1.8 on macOS is only 64 bit this combination is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your course material, and it does indeed contain a really old version of Eclipse - as greg-449 pointed out, there's no way this is going to work on macOS High Sierra. Really surprised instructions from 2007 haven't been updated, but that's another matter.

It would seem that your course just requires Java, so you can use the automated Installer that you find on this page: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and then choose the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers in the wizard. Or you can download that package directly [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/photon/R/eclipse-java-photon-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg), and install it.

Looking at your course material, it does appear that they have a custom plugin that makes regular Eclipse actions easier to execute, by adding a number of buttons to the Eclipse toolbar, you won't find these in a vanilla install. If you can find that plugin, you could try to install it into this version of Eclipse too, it might still work. If not, you can perform those steps manually - [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDrcE1kVDh4) will help, as he shows you how to import and run these projects without those plugins, it's not hard!

It's not possible to say if the plugin adds functionality beyond what is normally possible in general Eclipse distributions, but I doubt it does. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Brian. I think you are right about that eclipse version.