# how to solve this eclipse launch error?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried couple of answer to fix eclipse start-up problem.

I tried

```
eclipse.exe -clean didn't work. 
eclipse.exe -clean -data C:\prectice\java\ didn't work
eclipse.exe -clean --lanuncher.ini elipse.ini didn't work.
```

Here is the error:-

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\app\eclipse\configuration\1361558300022.log.
```

I have no clue how to launch eclipse. Please just me how can I fix it. Thanks in advnace!

Log file content:

```
!SESSION 2013-02-22 20:39:37.176 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-02-22 20:39:39.898
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mercury/javashared/agentloader/AgentBootstrap
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mercury.javashared.agentloader.AgentBootstrap
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: did you spell those commands right when u typed them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to run Eclipse Application. Can't even start Eclipse IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042824/not-able-to-run-eclipse-application-cant-even-start-eclipse-ide)

Comment: Do you have Quick Test Pro installed? Another issue exists on stackoverflow that resembles your problem where it was QTP related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clear these environment variables; the QTP brings them:

`JAVA_OPTIONS`:

```
-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

`IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS`:

```
-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`:

```
-agentlib:jvmhook
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also solved by creating a bat file for and blanking out the environment variables prior to launching the application, see the link for solution.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24685843/6345724

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to addie. You give me the clue about QTP. Actually I had QTP. It was ok together with QTP. But when I tried to uninstall qtp, it was not successful and left some file. So I find all files that comes with qtp and delete them manually. After removing all files, eclipse start normally.