# QTP and JAVA Application Issue

Tags: java, qtp

I have an issue with QTP 11 installed on our systems;

I have come across a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042824/not-able-to-run-eclipse-application-cant-even-start-eclipse-ide) in the Stack overflow, where I saw your following comment:

"**Check the JAVA_TOOL _OPTIONS variable. It probably has a value of "-agentlib:jvmhook". Clear the variable and Eclipse based products should start working.
You'll probably need to update your HP QT launcher to set this variable when you want to do profiling.**"

I wanted to know if there is any solution to our similar problem. The description is given below. I highly appreciate your expert help on this. We are new to this QTP and the related Clashes with JAVA.

If we do some task in our RCP JAVA App. it waits in the SWING UI thread...and restores after sometime.
(with QTP env variables in place)

IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS

```
-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
-agentlib:jvmhook

_JAVA_OPTIONS

```
-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

If we remove or rename these variables, the problem does not exist . Its clear that these variables are the culprits.
But we want these variables to co-exist with our JAVA App running so that the capturing happens properly.

We have tried all Online forums regarding this problem, and all users have settled for removing/renaming the environment variable, we are not aware how to go further. (even HP forums)

Some excerpts of the log is mentioned below, i hope you can get something out of it.

We get following errors in the Log in our RCP Log.
"Swing UI Thread is not responding"
"SWT UI Thread is not responding"

The part which is bothering me here is as follows:

```
Thread[Worker-1,5,main]/org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker [Alive]
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-2)
com.mercury.jacob.utils.EventHandlerUtils.invokeAndWait(EventHandlerUtils.java:141)
com.mercury.jacob.utils.EventHandlerUtils.invokeAndWait(EventHandlerUtils.java:115)
com.mercury.ftjadin.support.swt.cs.WidgetCS.getParent(WidgetCS.java:425)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:509)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:512)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.getWrapperObject(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:519)
com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.onCreate(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:562)
com.mercury.ftjadin.hooks.WToolkitHook.onCreate(WToolkitHook.java:23)
java.awt.Toolkit.createComponent(Toolkit.java:-1)
java.awt.Component.addNotify(Component.java:6862)
java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2758)
javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4743)
java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2769)
javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4743)
```

Thanks, 
madhukar

Edit:
Guys, the issue is now resolved with qtp latest update. It was an issue from their software.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem, what are the symptoms (just the log entries?), and how do you reproduce them?

Comment: @TheBlastOne The problem is with QTP in place and Variables set, my RCP/Java Application hangs..(waits for a long time in a thread), and then executes..

Comment: You don't have any QC/ALM window open in that situation, do you?