# Can't compile/run in Eclipse- Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, console

I'm trying to compile and run a simple program in Eclipse and whenever I hit run it says select what to run: and theres the option of two ant builds I have no clue what ant builds are or what to do about that.. when i try to run with the ant build it says "build failed: could not find an ant file to run"  I have the newest version of java and everything should be working fine but when I can never get past the ant build problem.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are your files in a java project?

Comment: Press `Alt+Shift+X`, then press `J`. What happens?

Comment: Alt+Shift+X, then press J -- nothing happens at all.. I'm on a mac I don't know  if that makes a difference

Comment: If someone get stuck with problem, please check this solution. It so differenent from another solutions and it helps me https://stackoverflow.com/a/47948092/7856586.

Answer (score 5):

First make sure that you made a regular "Java Project", and not something else.

If there's something wrong with the build configuration, which i guess there is, go to: Run > Run Configurations... On the left you will see a list of configurations, make sure your configuration runs as a "Java Application". If not, delete all the configurations by selecting them and then press delete.

If things are fine, your program should run normally

Comment: i originally created these java files on a different computer using dr java... they are .java files and should run.. i didn't create them in eclipse could that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Java Project by menu:
   File > New > Java Project
   Only the Project name is mandatory (if needed, you can configure all other options later).
2. Browse to your new project, and select the src folder.
3. New > Package
4. New > Class
   Make sure to select the checkbox to create: public static void main(...)
   This creates a runnable class.
5. Put some sample code to main(), e.g.:

   System.out.println("HALLO");
6. Select the class in Package Explorer and Run As > Java Application

Comment: okay after following that way of doing it that worked. how can i get my existing java files that i created on dr. java ide to work on eclipse?

Comment: You need to Import your sources to Eclipse project.

Comment: Select the src folder and run: Import... > File System > Next, Browse to the location of your sources, make sure to select them.

Answer (score 0):

Add `buildCommand` and `nature` tags in your `.project` file. You have to add Java Nature if you execute your project as Java project. `Run As...` menus are decided from the natures.

```
<projectDescription>
    ...
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```