# Eclipse Kepler - Inaccessible

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm unable to launch my Eclipse Kepler due to some error, as you could see in the log below. Please check and help me in fixing this issue.

```
!SESSION 2015-01-13 12:42:12.420 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_43
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-13 12:42:18.451
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mercury/javashared/agentloader/AgentBootstrap
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:480)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:666)
                at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:154)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:96)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mercury.javashared.agentloader.AgentBootstrap
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                ... 17 more
```

I have tried searching for some solution, but couldn't find any solution for this problem. Moreover, I'm completely new to this application and trying to launch it just today. So couldn't find the possible solution. Please help!!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to run Eclipse Application. Can't even start Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042824/not-able-to-run-eclipse-application-cant-even-start-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading just the [platform runtime](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.2-201402211700/#PlatformRuntime) as zip, extract it to a clean directory and execute eclipse.exe

You can also try starting from the command line with `eclipse.exe -clean -data C:\path\to\empty\workspace`

Comment: I've tried it, but no luck! Actually, I'm trying to use eclipse in following machine setup: **Windows 7, 64bit OS | jdk1.7.0_51, 32bit.** And I've tried with `eclipse-SDK-4.3.2-win32.zip`, but getting similar type of error. But, if I update the `-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe` in `eclipse.ini` file and access the eclipse, it throws error like _Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine_ **&** _Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit_ **&** _Java was started but returned exit code=1_. Please help!

Comment: I don't have option to upgrade the JDK to 64 bit, so please suggest me some possible remedies to use eclipse in this environment. Similar version of eclipse what I try to use is working in another machine, but not working in mine!! Tried to match both the machines as much as possible, but still I'm facing access issues!!!