# Error on startup eclipse java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -2147483647 > 1

Tags: java, eclipse

On launch of eclipse it shows logo and vanishes after some time it asks me to check logs in configuration folder
there it shows this error

```
!SESSION 2023-10-10 18:33:46.464 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.20.0.I20210611-1600
java.version=16.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2023-10-10 18:50:13.480
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -2147483647 > 1
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3781)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3741)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.lambda$6(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:391)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createUniqueWorkspaceNameMap(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createRecentWorkspacesComposite(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createDialogArea(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.showChooseWorkspaceDialog(IDEApplication.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)
```

i have already increased heap size from 256 to 1500 and tried in between also
deleted metadata of workspace also

no solution

Comment: Show us the full error log starting from the `!SESSION` line. Note that deleting the metadata is an extremely bad idea as you will loose all sorts of settings and it rarely fixes anything. What version of Eclipse? What version of Java?

Comment: added relevant info

Comment: Move to a stable release of Java, like Java 17. Java 16 has been end of life for years and was never meant to be used long-term.

Comment: Time to upgrade to IntelliJ ;-)

Comment: The first thing to do is try with the current Eclipse 2023-09 rather than a release which is now 2 years and 9 releases old. Most current releases include a suitable Java 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---\eclipse\configuration\.settings

go to this location

this is a file name
org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

here you will find all workspace which were shown as recent workspace on launch any one of those is corrupted, try removing it
it will start

Answer (score -1):

1. Check eclipse.ini file and verify jdk/jre paths. Infact all paths are correct.
2. Run this command

> eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState

3. Maybe your workspace is corrupted. Try to look in to workspace configuration or create new workspace.
   Please comment if none of these worked.
4. [Follow this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042824/not-able-to-run-eclipse-application-cant-even-start-eclipse-ide/47948092#47948092:%7E:text=That%20should%20mean%20a%20workspace%20issue)
5. Upgrade Eclipse

Comment: where do i run this commnad

Comment: Goto path where eclipse exe file is located. Open command prompt at that path and run this command.

Comment: no change same issue